# adding multiple element to eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I have a form that have two input which will take two numbers like below. And display the result of each calculation based on the math operators. How do I get the two input value and add it to eventListener to monitor value changes and update the result based on each math operator.

```
<div class="form">
  <input class="input" id="firstNum" />
  <input class="input" id="secondNum" />
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
   <h3>Addition</h3>
   <p id="addition"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
   <h3>Substraction</h3>
   <p id="substraction"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
   <h3>Multiplication</h3>
   <p id="multiplication"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
   <h3>Division</h3>
   <p id="division"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

operator.js export each math operators.

```
export function addition (a, b) { 
    return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)
}

export function substraction (a, b) { 
    return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)
}

export function multiplication (a, b) { 
    return parseInt(a) * parseInt(b)
}

export function division (a, b) { 
    return (a / b).toFixed(1)
}
```

script.js

```
import * as mathOperator from "./operators.js"

document.querySelectorAll(".input")
    .forEach(function (element) { 
        element.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
            let a = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("id")
            let b = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("id")
            console.log(a, b)
            document.getElementById("addition").textContent = mathOperator.addition(a, b)
            document.getElementById("substraction").textContent = mathOperator.substraction(a, b)
            document.getElementById("multiplication").textContent = mathOperator.multiplication(a, b)
            document.getElementById("division").textContent = mathOperator.division(a, b)
        })
    })
```

Comment: There are no event listeners in your code, have you missed out part of the example?

Comment: @DBS I updated the code from what I have tried, how do I get the value for both input? I tried .value but I don't think its the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select the values using the ids and do calculation.

Sample implementation.

```js
function addition(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)
}

function substraction(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)
}

function multiplication(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a) * parseInt(b)
}

function division(a, b) {
  return b === 0 ? 0 : (a / b).toFixed(1)
}

function calculate() {
  const a = document.getElementById("firstNum").value || 0;
  const b = document.getElementById("secondNum").value || 0;
  document.getElementById("addition").textContent = addition(a, b)
  document.getElementById("substraction").textContent = substraction(a, b)
  document.getElementById("multiplication").textContent = multiplication(a, b)
  document.getElementById("division").textContent = division(a, b)
}

document.querySelectorAll(".input")
  .forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      calculate()
    })
  })
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input class="input" id="firstNum" />
  <input class="input" id="secondNum" />
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h3>Addition</h3>
    <p id="addition"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h3>Substraction</h3>
    <p id="substraction"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h3>Multiplication</h3>
    <p id="multiplication"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h3>Division</h3>
    <p id="division"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the approach, I appreciate it so much.